# introduce time delay before continuing execution

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I need to introduce a time delay in the program. I'm using C and GTk3+. I tried to use the function sleep(), but this seems to stop the execution of the program well before the instruction is encountered. Is there any better alternative? This is what I tried

```
...
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image_1), ".../a.png");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image_2), "../b.png");
    sleep(3);
    gtk_widget_show(image_1]);
    gtk_widget_show(image_2);
..
```

Comment: never do a `sleep` in a graphical application

Comment: Did you look at timer functions like ´g_timeout_add`?

Comment: How can a program sleep before the sleep command is encountered? Prefetching made wrong...